# Applying a role under sudo user

Tags: ansible

Is it possible to apply a specific role as sudo in Ansible?

Specifically, these are roles fetched from ansible-galaxy, so the source is not within my control.

[This example](https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Ansible_-_Better_sudo_control.html) suggests that passing `sudo:yes` to the role should work, but I presume the role must first be defined to expect the param.

[This section](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/CHANGELOG.md#13-top-of-the-world---september-13th-2013) of the changelog suggests that `sudo true` can be set at the role level, however, the following is not working:

```
---
- remote_user: "vagrant"
  tasks: []
  hosts: "all"
  roles:
  - role: "mysql"
    sudo: yes
```

However, applying sudo at the top level makes the role work:

```
---
- remote_user: "vagrant"
  tasks: []
  hosts: "all"
  sudo: yes
  roles:
  - role: "mysql"
```

Note -- I've tried with both `sudo: true` and `sudo: yes`, and the outcome is the same.

Comment: what happens if you change `sudo: True` to `sudo: yes` ?

Comment: Same outcome -- the role is not run using sudo.

Comment: What's your Ansible version?  I'm having the same problem with Ansible 2.2 and a third party [MySQL role](https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-role-mysql) that says either mode should work.  Running the role with a `sudo: yes` (actually `become`) makes a shell command fail due to permissions, while running it with `become: yes` at the play level works.  Clearly an Ansible bug as role-level `become` should work.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can perform a role as another user, including root, but only at the "playbook" level.

If you want to run one role as yourself, and another role as, say, "root", then you'll have to write those up as separate plays (whether or not they are in separate files).

For example, assuming that you have this playbook, containing two plays, using the same role, but with different `sudo` users:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  sudo: yes
  roles:
  - role: aks.whoami

- hosts: localhost
  sudo: no
  roles:
  - role: aks.whoami
```

And, this role: `aks.whoami`:

```
---
- name: "whoami?"
  shell: whoami
  register: whoami

- debug: var=whoami.stdout
```

This is the output:

```
PLAY [localhost] **************************************************************

GATHERING FACTS ***************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK: [aks.whoami | whoami?] **************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK: [aks.whoami | debug var=whoami.stdout] **********************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "var": {
        "whoami.stdout": "root"
    }
}

PLAY [localhost] **************************************************************

GATHERING FACTS ***************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK: [aks.whoami | whoami?] **************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK: [aks.whoami | debug var=whoami.stdout] **********************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "var": {
        "whoami.stdout": "aks"
    }
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=6    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Comment: I think OP wants to escalate privileges on a `per-role` basic, not all roles

Comment: That's what the example shows. One role gets invoked with sudo privs, one doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me, but not the `sudo: yes`.

```
roles:
  - { role: packages, become: yes}
  - { role: geerlingguy.docker, become: yes }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [according to this post](https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Ansible_-_Better_sudo_control.html), it is possible to do like this:

```
---
- hosts: new-servers
  user: username
  connection: ssh # or paramiko

  roles:
    - { role: basic-debian-setup, sudo: yes }
    - { role: git-setup }
    - { role: vim }
    - { role: bash }
    - { role: screen }
    - { role: openssh, sudo: yes }
    - { role: sudo, sudo: yes }
    - { role: postfix, sudo: yes }
    - { role: vnstat, sudo: yes }
```

Note that you can also do this with `when:` clauses and in role's `meta/main.yml` dependencies list like this:

```
dependencies:
  - { role: 'geerlingguy.repo-epel', sudo: true, when: "ansible_os_family == 'RedHat' and ansible_distribution_major_version | version_compare('6', '<=')" }
```