# Is there anyway to run multiple Ansible playbooks as multiple users more efficiently?

Tags: ansible

Currently my playbook structure is like this:

```
~/test_ansible_roles ❯❯❯ tree .
.
├── checkout_sources
│   └── tasks
│       └── main.yml
├── install_dependencies
│   └── tasks
│       └── main.yml
├── make_dirs
│   └── tasks
│       └── main.yml
├── setup_machine.yml
```

One of the roles that I have is to install dependencies on my box, so for this I need `sudo`. Because of that all of my other tasks I need to include the stanza:

```
   become: yes
   become_user: my_username
```

Is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: why not only write `sudo=yes` in the install task?

Comment: Isn't sudo=yes deprecated ?

Comment: you are right, it's deprecated but you can also use become_user per task. See this [stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21344777/how-to-switch-a-user-per-task-or-set-of-tasks)

Comment: I am already doing that. Just wanted to know if there is a better way.

Comment: You may run install_dependencies role as another user while including it like this [stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31663592/applying-a-role-under-sudo-user)

Answer (score 12):

You can set the `become` options per:

- play
- role
- task

**Per play:**

```
- hosts: whatever
  become: true
  become_user: my_username
  roles:
    - checkout_sources
    - install_dependencies
    - make_dirs
```

**Per role:**

```
- hosts: whatever
  roles:
    - checkout_sources
    - role: install_dependencies
      become: true
      become_user: my_username
    - make_dirs
```

**Per task:**

```
- shell: do something
  become: true
  become_user: my_username
```

You can combine this however you like. The play can run as user A, a role as user B and finally a task inside the role as user C.

Defining `become` per play or role is rarely needed. If a single task inside a role requires sudo it should only be defined for that specific task and not the role.

If multiple tasks inside a role require `become`, [blocks](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_blocks.html) come in handy to avoid recurrence:

```
- block:
    - shell: do something
    - shell: do something
    - shell: do something
  become: true
  become_user: my_username
```

Comment: When I run the playbook with -K, the beginning user that I am starting with is "root" is that correct ?

Comment: I don't think so.  `--ask-sudo-pass` (or now `--ask-become-pass`) should only prompt for the password used for sudo/become, but not automatically force a user for the complete playbook.

Comment: I have tried this, and in my checkout_sources, it checkout out the sources as root.